# Operation on the sorted dataframe between the first row and the last row of same ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which shows the transaction history of members.

I had sorted them  in ascending with respect to the `msno`, `transaction_date` and 'membership_expire_date'. I wish to generate a new column which can calculate how long the member is with us. For example, the member of `+++hVY1rZox/33YtvDgmKA2Frg/2qhkz12B9ylCvh8o=` perform transaction from 2016-11-16 to 2017-02-15. I can calculate the number of months by them.

Any better method instead of doing a `for` loop throughout the rows(about hundred thousands row) and `if` condition to identify the first row and last row of that particular member and then perform subtraction on the transaction_date?

```
 msno transaction_date membership_expire_date  payment_plan_days
6797850   +++FOrTS7ab3tIgIh8eWwX4FqRv8w/FoiOuyXsFvphY=       2016-09-09             2016-09-14                  5
1521480   +++IZseRRiQS9aaSkH6cMYU6bGDcxUieAi/tH67sC5s=       2015-11-21             2017-01-04                410
1498592   +++hVY1rZox/33YtvDgmKA2Frg/2qhkz12B9ylCvh8o=       2016-11-16             2016-12-15                 29
17923235  +++hVY1rZox/33YtvDgmKA2Frg/2qhkz12B9ylCvh8o=       2016-12-15             2017-01-15                 31
58566     +++hVY1rZox/33YtvDgmKA2Frg/2qhkz12B9ylCvh8o=       2017-01-15             2017-02-15                 31
1914756   +++hVY1rZox/33YtvDgmKA2Frg/2qhkz12B9ylCvh8o=       2017-02-15             2017-03-15                 28
7798380   +++l/EXNMLTijfLBa8p2TUVVVp2aFGSuUI/h7mLmthw=       2015-01-31             2015-03-19                 47
14494860  +++l/EXNMLTijfLBa8p2TUVVVp2aFGSuUI/h7mLmthw=       2015-02-28             2015-04-19                 50
11014601  +++l/EXNMLTijfLBa8p2TUVVVp2aFGSuUI/h7mLmthw=       2015-03-31             2015-05-19                 49
13256589  +++l/EXNMLTijfLBa8p2TUVVVp2aFGSuUI/h7mLmthw=       2015-04-30             2015-06-19                 50
18984021  +++l/EXNMLTijfLBa8p2TUVVVp2aFGSuUI/h7mLmthw=       2015-05-31             2015-07-19                 49
```

Comment: Please [don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Better is small data sample with desired output, [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is best.

Comment: Anyway, the solution to this is doing a diff on the date columns, grouping by ID and finding the sum.

Comment: Noted on the image of code. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding upon my comment, use `sub` + `groupby`:

```
df.membership_expire_date.sub(df.transaction_date)\
                          .dt.days.groupby(df.msno).sum()

msno
+++FOrTS7ab3tIgIh8eWwX4FqRv8w/FoiOuyXsFvphY=      5
+++IZseRRiQS9aaSkH6cMYU6bGDcxUieAi/tH67sC5s=    410
+++hVY1rZox/33YtvDgmKA2Frg/2qhkz12B9ylCvh8o=    119
+++l/EXNMLTijfLBa8p2TUVVVp2aFGSuUI/h7mLmthw=    245
```

If those columns are not `datetime` columns, use `pd.to_datetime`, or `parse_dates` argument when loading your CSV.

---

If you want to add a new column to your existing dataframe, use `transform` + `sum`:

```
s = df.membership_expire_date.sub(df.transaction_date)\
                    .dt.days.groupby(df.msno).transform('sum')    
s

6797850       5
1521480     410
1498592     119
17923235    119
58566       119
1914756     119
7798380     245
14494860    245
11014601    245
13256589    245
18984021    245
dtype: int64

df['diff'] = s
```

Comment: The method that add a new column to my existing dataframe works like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is set a key on the dataframe, so you can query against each `msno`:

```
df_key = df.set_index(['msno'], validate=False)

msno = '+++FOrTS7ab3tIgIh8eWwX4FqRv8w/FoiOuyXsFvphY='

first_row = df_key[msno].iloc[0]
last_row = df_key[msno].iloc[-1]
```

Then you can do your calculations, e.g.

```
last_row['payment_plan_days'] - first_row['payment_plan_days']
```

If you have a full key, it's probably better to actually use that as an index and do validate=True, but this should work like a charm -- and you benefit from pandas optimisations, unlike with the loop

Comment: This is extremely inefficient. Do _not_ do this (actually, did you misread the question?).